# How can I reduce the number of passphrases that I must memorize (password manager, FDE, user accounts)?

Tags: password-management

I'm attempting to reduce the number of passphrases that I must memorize. Currently I need a different passphrase for each of:

1. Password manager
2. FDE for my personal computer
3. User account for my personal computer
4. FDE for my work computer
5. User account for my work computer

I also have an encrypted backup drive for my personal computer and one for my work computer, but I assume it should be safe to reuse my FDE (Full-Disk Encryption) passphrases for my encrypted backup drives, since they protect the same data using the same method.

So, that's five passphrases that I must remember. I assume the password manager and FDE passphrases should be the most secure, so at least six-word Diceware passphrases. So that's three different six-word passphrases to remember. I don't know how secure the user account passwords need to be (assume that both of the computers are protected by firewall and are not available via SSH).

Some questions:

- How can I reduce the number of passphrases that I must memorize?
- Can some combination of these passphrases be safely reused? What might be the risks involved?
- How strong should my user account passphrases be? Could I use very short passphrases, e.g. two or three words?
- Could I use some type of passwordless authentication for any of these?

I realize there are probably no obviously best solutions here since it will depend on my individual threat model. As I'm not exactly sure what my threat model is, I'm mostly looking for ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Put all that in a phone's password manager and just memorise one.

Comment: This question is a little all over the place. Some of what you asked can't be answered. "How strong?" is unanswerable without more details. "Can I use passwordless?" depends on whether all these things allow it, so we can't answer that either. We have questions here on how/if to use the same password for accounts.